# Oro platform workflow - create_entity

Tags: php, yaml, oroplatform

I am working with Oro, and I am trying to create new entity when workflow is started. I've setup everything (at least I think so), according to documentation, but my entity is created without proper fields. The part of the workflow yml, responsible for createing the entity:

```
workflows:
    sample_flow:
        transition_definitions:
            sample_transition_definition:
                actions:
                  - '@create_entity':
                      class: Path\To\Entity
                      attribute: $entity
                      data:
                          desc: $value1
                          started: $value2
                          ended: $value3
                          ....
```

I tried to change the fields in data, no luck. If I change them to like:

```
workflows:
    sample_flow:
        transition_definitions:
            sample_transition_definition:
                actions:
                  - '@create_entity':
                      class: Path\To\Entity
                      attribute: $entity
                      data:
                          desc: 'test'
                          started: 'tetst 2'
                          ....
```

The entity than contains them, but I need this fields to be set from inputed values. Any idea what I am doing wrong, or what I can check?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure value1, value2, and value3 are defined as attributes; they are set in a form and then used in actions.

Comment: I am working on an existing codebase. While searching for the form, I noticed that values it is actuall defined in vue component...I am stuck..